# Summing costs of cell depending on the values in three other cells - Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to calculate the costs of purchased items for each business for every month. The problem I'm experiencing is that it will sum the whole of column `B`. This is my current formula: `=SUMPRODUCT(C:C)+(COUNTIFS(G5,A:A))`. This `Qty` is a negative number as they are being removed from the store room and then charged to the business.

Below is my current table I am working with:
[image]

Any help with this much appreciated!

Comment: Is your "Cost" column, the cost EACH? Or TOTAL COST? I assume it is cost each, and there would be a much simpler solution is you are able to add a TOTAL COST column. As you could then just use `SUMIFS`.

Comment: It is actually the TOTAL COST

Comment: Just use a Pivot Table.  Or, if you MUST use formulas, use `SUMIFS`

Comment: Can you please add some expected results for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use a pivot table. However, I generally dislike them as I prefer to have more control over them than what Excel gives me.

There is no need to use SUMPRODUCT. SUMIFS is the formula you are looking for:

```
=SUMIFS($C:$C,$D:$D,$F5,$A:$A,G$4)
```

[image]

I'd suggest not using whole column references, but if it's only a small workbook, it shouldn't cause too much slow down.

I would suggest converting your data to an excel table. You can then refer to the data by column name.

Comment: I believe the OP is looking to multiply column B * C to get the total. If so this won't work.

Comment: @Kevin No he isn't. I thought that at first, but he confirmed in the comments that his "Cost" column is actually the Total Cost. Even if it weren't, it would be simple to add a Total Cost column.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you want to sum the cost for each Business unit for each month. This formula should work with slight adjustment on your part (since I can't see your columns/rows).

[image: Example Sheet]

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$50=G$2)*($D$2:$D$50=$F3)*($C$2:$C$50*$B$2:$B$50))

- or if column "C" is the total

=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$50=G$2)*($D$2:$D$50=$F3)*($C$2:$C$50))
```

Change `G2`to your month criteria

Change `F3`to your business criteria

And change your ranges accordingly

To break this down:

```
(A2:A50=G2) - Gets the cells that match the month criteria
(D2:D50=F3) - Gets the cells that match the business criteria
(C2:C50*B2:B50) - Multiply the Qty * Cost
```

Comment: As you want to drag the formula downwards and sideways, some `$` should be added. Probably like this: `=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$50=G$2)*($D$2:$D$50=$F3)*($C$2:$C$50*$B$2:$B$50))`.

Comment: @OverflowStacker - I agree, I would also used named ranges if I was doing this...